# How to scrape span ids' texts in beautifulsoup in the following html?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div align="justify" style="text-align: center">
    <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder" style="width:555px;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Book</th>
                <th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Issue Date</th>
                <th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Submition Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_0">Engineering Mechanics</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label2_0">17-Oct-2016</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label3_0">31-Oct-2016</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_1">ATB of Engineering Mathematics</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label2_1">17-Oct-2016</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label3_1">31-Oct-2016</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the text `Engineering mechanics` and it's corresponding date (text) `31-Oct-2016` and the text`ATB of Engineering Mathematics` and it's corresponding date (text) `31-Oct-2016`. All of these all located in the span ids. How can I extract and print them? I'm new to web scraping.

Comment: first you can `find_all()` `tr` tags, and using loop you can `find_all()` `td` in every `tr`. This way you can control scraped data.

Comment: @furas Sir, May you give me the code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use `find_all()` to find all `tr` tags, and using loop you can use `find_all()` to find all `span` tags in every `tr`. This way you can control scraped data

```
html = '''<div align="justify" style="text-align: center">
                                            <div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder" style="width:555px;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Book</th><th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Issue Date</th><th class="grdheading2" scope="col">Submition Date</th>
</tr><tr>
<td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_0">Engineering Mechanics</span>
</td><td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label2_0">17-Oct-2016</span>
</td><td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label3_0">31-Oct-2016</span>
                                                        </td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_1">ATB of Engineering Mathematics</span>
</td><td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label2_1">17-Oct-2016</span>
</td><td>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label3_1">31-Oct-2016</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    spans = tr.find_all('span')
    if spans:
        print 'title:', spans[0].text
        print 'date:',  spans[2].text
```

Result

```
title: Engineering Mechanics
date: 31-Oct-2016
title: ATB of Engineering Mathematics
date: 31-Oct-2016
```